# React-Native AWS-SDK : Can't upload image to S3 buckets Error: "SignatureDoesNotMatch"

Tags: react-native, pytorch, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js

I'm using the AWS-SDK with react-native to upload an image to S3 Bucket.
First of all, I want to say that my access and connectivity works well, I tried uploading plain text it works, I tried listing the objects and the buckets it works too.

Here is my code:

```
async function handleImage(capturedImage) {
    setImage(capturedImage);
    setScreenState(ScreenStates.LOADING);
    try {


      const result = await classifyImage(capturedImage);
      console.log(result.tensor_)
      // {dtype:"float32",shape:[…]}
      //  dtype:"float32"
      //  shape:[1,3,273,224]

      const blob_jpeg = new Blob([result.tensor_], {type: "image/jpeg"});
      console.log(typeof blob_jpeg._data)
      // object

      console.log(blob_jpeg._data)
      // {blobId:"e7a667ad-4363-4a2e-9850-8695f103e9e0",offset:0,size:1489546,type:"image/jpeg",__collector:{}}

      try {
        const keyName = 'image.jpeg';
        const putCommand = new PutObjectCommand({
          Bucket: "mybucket",
          ContentType:"image/jpeg",
          Key: "myimage",
          Body:  blob_jpeg._data,
        });
    
        await s3.send(putCommand);
        console.log(
          'Successfully uploaded data to ' + bucketName + '/' + keyName);

      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e,e);
      }
```

My error:

```
Error: "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method." in SignatureDoesNotMatch: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method. <<     at construct (native) <<     at apply (native) <<     at i (@aws-sdk/client-s3.js:3:461197)
```

Any ideas about how can I solve this problem and succesffully upload my image ?